# How can I write directive for input and text area

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote a directive for input focus & blur

```
 angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('input', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (element && element[0] && element[0].placeholder) {
        scope.placeholder = element[0].placeholder;
        element.bind("focus", function() {
          console.log(scope.placeholder);
          element[0].placeholder = "";
        });
        element.bind("blur", function() {
          element[0].placeholder = $filter('translate')(scope.placeholder);
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

I want same functionality for text area also. But don't wanted to write an other directive. How I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var myDirective = ['$filter', function($filter) {
     return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: true,
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         if (element && element[0] && element[0].placeholder) {
            scope.placeholder = element[0].placeholder;
            element.bind("focus", function() {
            console.log(scope.placeholder);
            element[0].placeholder = "";
         });
         element.bind("blur", function() {
           element[0].placeholder = $filter('translate')(scope.placeholder);
         });
       }
     }
  };
}]

angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('input', myDirective);
  .directive('textarea', myDirective);
```

and in your html:

```
<input />
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have many fields of input & text area tags. Please give me suggestion in tag point of view..

Comment: Use `scope:true` in directive.

Comment: It's difficult for me add `pladeholder-directive` in every input & textarea. Please suggest other solution. Thnx

Comment: @Donthamsettivbhadrarao You can use the above approach